# Applying for internships - should I include 3 days' work experience from Year 10?

Tags: resume, internship, applications, work-experience

Back in year 10, I did 3 days of work experience (the school made all students do work experience). I am now a university freshman applying for internships, and am not sure whether to include it on my resume as it was for a short time period.

The work experience is not really related to the internships I am applying for, but it may back up my soft skills?? I don't really want to include it, but I don't have any other work to list on my resume.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that three day's worth isn't enough to warrant its own section. I was told that as a first year university student, your high school experience counts, but will start to matter less as you progress through each year. But since at this point all you have are high school experiences, try to categorize it with like-experiences.

School Activities:

- Volunteered with Club A
- Worked for three days with Program X
- President of Club B

On that note, it's OK to not have any experience when you first apply, hence the need to apply. What you can market are your interests, skills, and potentially volunteer (non-paid) experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip it, as it is hard to demonstrate learning or knowledge gained in the timeline. It is OK not to list work experience being a freshman. I would suggest adding your project work from the course that could demonstrate skills aligned to the role you are applying for.

Best of Luck.